# Loading huge data to Dynamodb is very slow using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to load more than 20 million records to my Dynamodb table using below code from EMR 5 node cluster. But it is taking more hours and hours time to load completely. I have much more huge data to load, but i want to load it in span of few minutes. How to achieve this?

Below is my code. I just changed original column names and I have 20 columns to insert. The problem here is with slow loading.

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb','us-west')
table = dynamodb.Table('EMP')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='emp-rec.json')
records = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'), parse_float = decimal.Decimal)

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
     for rec in records:
         batch.put_item(Item=rec)
```

Comment: word of warning to anyone viewing this, for whatever reason RK changed his question to conform with John Rotenstein's answer which makes this post confusing to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should use Amazon CloudWatch to check whether you are hitting limits for your configure Write Capacity Units on the table. If so, you can increase the capacity, at least for the duration of the load.

Second, the code is creating **batches of one record**, which wouldn't be very efficient. The `batch_writer()` can be used to process multiple records, such as in this sample code from the [`batch_writer()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.batch_writer):

```
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for _ in xrange(1000000):
        batch.put_item(Item={'HashKey': '...',
                             'Otherstuff': '...'})
```

Notice how the `for` loop is *inside* the `batch_writer()`? That way, multiple records are stored within one batch. Your code sample, however, has the `for` *outside* of the `batch_writer()`, which results in a batch size of one.

Comment: Yup sure ! Thank you so much for your response. I'll try the recommended change. Mean while, i found BatchWriteItemInput also loads very quick. So, i would like to know which is better here while loading huge data.

Comment: I do not know. Give them both a try and let us know what you find!

Comment: The sample code is merely using range to demonstrate that you can have many items in a batch. Your code would simply use `for rec in records` within the `with`.

Comment: There is no need to use range. Your `for` loop is more appropriate.

Comment: the speed of batch import and one per time is the same (